# How to map over an array that is yet to exist?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, destructuring

I am currently triggering an API call that returns an array of two objects. The trigger is instigated by user input and will yield an output after pressing a button

Here is the code:

```
  const [curQuery, setCurQuery] = useState("");

  const [curOutput, setCurOutput] = useState("Empty");
  

  const handleClick = (query) => {
        
   setCurOutput(myApiCall.queryItems(curQuery));
      
  };

 console.log(curOutput);
```

The current output log looks like this:

```
  > (2) [myResults, myResults]
               0: myResult
               id: 00
               description: "Here is the main description of Type 1"
    
               1: myResult
               id: 01
               description: "Here is the main description of Type 2"
```

I am only interested in the description, I can currently access it like **myOutput[0].description** and **myOutput[1].description** to access the respective values, but would like to skim across all entries and collect the **descriptions** only.

One suggestion is to map over the array and collect the values as follows:

```
  const descriptions = curOutput.map((v) => v.descriptions);
```

The issue is that this unfourtunetly crashes my program as my query is yet to be defined

```
return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="myInput"
        placeholder="typeQuery"
        value={curQuery}
        onChange={(e) => setCurQuery(e.target.value)}
      />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleClick(curQuery);
        }}
      >
        Request Items based on query
      </button>
   </div>
  );
```

As you can see above, I am setting the current query based on user input and then submitting that input once the user has finished typing.

How do I juggle these in order for my program to work and return the relevant descriptions based on the request?

Comment: Just `.map()` them? `const descriptions = myOutput.map(v => v.description)` and now you have only descriptions.

Comment: it says that myOutput.map is not a function, yet myOutput[0].description renders as exepcted. Not sure why this is

Comment: Then it's time to find out what `myOutput` is. `console.log({ myOutput })` (with curly braces) and see what it says

Comment: i'm really sorry but it outputs exactly what i've detailed above

Comment: I am going to write a new question to understand this error

Comment: The console log tells you want object type this is. Because if `.map` doesn't exist, it's not an array: update your post to explain what it really is. And no, don't write a new question, get the details necessary, and [put them in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246659/discussion-between-kevin-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Comment: I must decline: if you're dealing with an array, `.map` will work. If `.map` does not work, it's not an array: mention what it really is in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a fallback array in case the variable is not yet defined like this:

```js
const descriptions = (curOutput || []).map((v) => v.descriptions);
```

Or just pass an empty array to useState's initial value

```js
const [curOutput, setCurOutput] = useState([]);
```

Also keep in mind that your `myApiCall.queryItems(curQuery)` might be async and for example returns a `Promise` instead of returning the result directly. You could then do something like this:

```js
myApiCall.queryItems(curQuery).then(result => setCurOutput(result));
```